# React, onClick callback arguments

Tags: reactjs

why react set onClick callback three arguments?

`nativeEvent` can get by `proxyEvent.nativeEvent`. Why React `set nativeEvent` at the third argument.

If I click the button, `console.log(args)` give me `Proxy, undefined, Event`, the third argument is not what i want.

but in `componentDidMount`, call `this.clickHandler`, it give me `null, null, 'b2c'`, the third argument 'b2c' that's what i want.

```js
class ReactEventArgument extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
        this.clickHandler(null, null, 'b2c');
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <Child clickHandler={this.clickHandler}></Child>
        </div>  
    }

    clickHandler = (e, v, type = 'b2c') => {
        console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        console.log(e, v, type);
    
        //if I click the button, I get a wrong type, type is nativeEvent, not my argument.
    }
} 

class Child extends React.Component{
    render() {
        const {clickHandler} = this.props;
        return <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={clickHandler}>click me</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

I have to change the `button` like this:

`<button type="button" onClick={e => clickHandler(e, null, undefined)}>click me too</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful with ProxyEvents, even console.log'ing them (in Chrome for example) won't give you their true value as they are intended to be shortlived.

That aside, the simplest way is to do something like:

```
class Child extends React.Component{

    clickHandler(type = 'b2c') {
        console.log(type);  // 1) coming from button, then output will be foobar
                            // 2) coming from something else that 
                            //    doesn't pass in anything, output will be b2c
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.clickHandler("foobar")}>click me</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed your comment to the other answer, regarding the third argument. Unless you need the "e" variable (for example, I sometimes use it for input values `e.target.value`), then just don't pass it through

Answer (score 1):

React explains its event stuff [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html). When you call the event handler explicitly like this, you're not passing in the same stuff that react would send to you on in a typical event handler. If you need to call it explicitly like that, use a 4th argument so it remains usable by react. Otherwise, just simply call a function inside your event handler that does what you need and instead call that function inside componentWillMount.

For example:

```
class ReactEventArgument extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
        this.customFunction('b2c');
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <Child clickHandler={this.clickHandler}></Child>
        </div>  
    }

    customFunction = (type) => {
      // do your stuff here
    }

    clickHandler = (e) => {
        this.customFunction('b2c')
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I know the `doc`. My question is there are three default arguments pass into the event callback. `ProxyEvent`, `undefined`, `nativeEvent`. If I use third argument, can cause a error. The default third argument `nativeEvent` is not what I expect.